# AWS Aurora Migration; MySQL Partitioned Tables Don't Restore

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

We've just spun up an Aurora instance using a MySQL snapshot. Everything looks good except for our partitioned tables. In every case, partitioned tables appear in SHOW TABLES output but if we SELECT from the table, or run DESCRIBE or SHOW CREATE TABLE, we get an error saying the table does not exist. If we attempt to run queries against any partitioned table from a PHP client, Aurora throws the same error.

If we run a CREATE TABLE statement that uses partitions in the Aurora database, the statement runs without error.

Is there an issue with migrating partitioned tables? Anyone had a similar experience? Since Aurora is designed with really large databases in mind, I assume others are migrating partitioned tables.

Answer (score 3):

[Aurora](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/) does support migration of partitioned tables from RDS MySQL.

Early in the limited preview for Aurora, support for migrating partitioned tables had not yet been added. This is why you got the error message you described above. Now that Aurora is generally available it supports migration of partitioned tables.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Really assuaged my worries about migrating a partitioned table from MySQL to Aurora.